# Can i make curl page effect with EAGLView?

Tags: ios, eaglview, page-curl

I want to get the effect like Google Maps, but replace MapView with EAGLView.Is this possible and how?

I used [link](https://github.com/FairfaxMobile/FDCurlViewControl).It use UIView as targetView,there's something wrong when set targetView to EAGLView i'm not sure it support EAGLView

Comment: what have you done up to now? please update this question with what you have done also improve your accept rating.

Comment: 0% accept rating with 7 questions. That's pretty bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out XBPageCurl, https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl

i've not used it EAGLView, but it seems to work with any view

Comment: It does not work for EAGLView currently,look at author's explain:[link](https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl/issues/19)